# how can i do this with jquery? (its something created with flash)

Tags: jquery-ui

http://pal-auto.ebizautos.com/

if you look at that page above, there is something that looks like a carasel which operates when the mouse is over each item and slides to the left. does anyone know if anything like this exists in jquery already premade?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go on the jQuery site and search for accordion plug ins.

Comment: thanks that was the name i was trying to remember :p .. i knew i had seen it somewhere

Answer (score 1):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Kwicks](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks) does exactly what you're looking for: horizontal-accordion style navigation.

http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

- [7 Examples of Use](http://www.jeremymartin.name/examples/kwicks.php?example=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is an official accordion plugin included in the [jQuery.ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover) package that might do what you need.